# Filling NA's according to column type

Tags: r

assume a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    age= c(24, 22, NA, 13, 23),
    yes_no = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE),
    dummy = c(0,1,0,NA,0))
```

if we had hundreds of columns. how can we we fill the NA values according to the column type?

output may be like
(pseude code):

```
  if column is numeric:
        fill na with column mean
  else if column is boolean:
        delete row 
        # or (fill na with most frequent value)
  else if column is dummy(0-1)
      fill na with most frequent value (0 or 1)
```

any help?

Comment: The `dummy` column syntax is not `R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a user function `f` as the first step (assuming you have either `logical` or `numeric` type for columns in `df`)

```
f <- function(v) {
  cls <- class(v)
  na.idx <- which(is.na(v))
  mostFreqVal <- names(tail(sort(table(v)), 1))
  x <- ifelse(
    cls == "logical",
    as.logical(mostFreqVal),
    ifelse(
      all(unique(na.omit(v)) %in% c(0, 1)),
      as.numeric(mostFreqVal),
      mean(v, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  )
  replace(v, na.idx, x)
}
```

then try the base R option with `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(df,f)
> df
   age yes_no dummy
1 24.0   TRUE     0
2 22.0   TRUE     1
3 20.5   TRUE     0
4 13.0  FALSE     0
5 23.0   TRUE     0
```

or a `data.table` option like below

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, f)]
    age yes_no dummy
1: 24.0   TRUE     0
2: 22.0   TRUE     1
3: 20.5   TRUE     0
4: 13.0  FALSE     0
5: 23.0   TRUE     0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `na.aggregate` with `FUN` option

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
  # // loop across columns that are logical class or (`|`)      
  mutate(across(where(~ is.logical(.)|
         # // where  all the unique non-NA elements are 0 or 1
          all(unique(.[!is.na(.)]) %in% c(0, 1))), 
         # // replace the NA with the most frequent value
          ~ na.aggregate(., FUN = Mode)),
     # // where the columns are numeric, replace NA with mean
     # // FUN by default in na.aggregate is mean
     across(where(is.numeric), na.aggregate))
```

-output

```
#   age yes_no dummy
#1 24.0   TRUE     0
#2 22.0   TRUE     1
#3 20.5   TRUE     0
#4 13.0  FALSE     0
#5 23.0   TRUE     0
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```